# How to remove this Ubuntu file under Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

How can I remove this Ubuntu file under Linux completely and install it again?

[image]

Comment: Restore a backup

Comment: @GillesQuenot How can I do it? Do you mean a backup of Linux？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: before you do anything please check if you have any important files on the wsl and if so please back them up or save them somewhere else.

It looks like your on a windows machine -> this is not a ubuntu file it is your (wsl) ubuntu vm. If you open the folder you should see the basic folders you encounter in every linux machine (folders like /etc, /home, /usr and so on).

In order to uninstall the ubuntu vm and reinstall just...

- press Windows (meta) key > Add or remove programs > search "Ubuntu" > Click on Ubuntu > Click "uninstall"

Now you can install the ubuntu wsl if you go to...

- Microsoft Store > search ubuntu > install